# Adding ASMX service to IIS for use with Biztalk

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, biztalk, asmx

I've created a local webservice (.asmx), that I want to add to IIS. The service needs to be called from a Send Adapter in Biztalk.

My project in Visual Studio is structured like so:

[image]

There's a single .asmx file, that contains a single web method, see code below:

```
public class LocalWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        private BankConnectClient client;
        [WebMethod]
        public void TransferPayment()
        {
            ProcessDirectory("C:\\Test\\BankConnectTestFiles");
        }
```

I'm not very familiar with IIS, so I don't know best approch to add this service to run on my localhost. I tried adding a new website and placed the project folder in C:\inetpub\wwwroot, which I then reference in IIS with the following settings:
[image]

But when I browse to the root http://localhost:61406/, I receive an HTTP Error 403.14.

What is the correct approach in deploying an asmx web service to IIS, to then call in Biztalk using either the WCF-Custom or WCF-BasicHttp adapter?

Comment: The URL is wrong. ASMX web service URL must include the actual .asmx file name and method name. Besides,  most people today use ASP.NET Web API or ASP.NET Core, which you should seriously consider.

Comment: What authentication did you configure in IIS?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I included the .asmx file in my URL and gave permission to the folder for the service account that was running the service. It seems to work as expected now. I considered using ASP.NET Web API, but I wanted to keep things simple, as I need to call this service from Biztalk. I understand the WCF adapters mostly work with .svc services, but that some of them still support .asmx.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem has been solved. The service URL need the LocalWebService.asmx suffix.
Besides, as far as I know, BasicHttpBinding in the WCF aims to compatible with ASMX web service, why not try to create a WCF service with BasicHttpBinding. And this is also supported by the BizTalk.
I Have made a demo, wish it is useful to you.
**VS template.**
[image]
Add the following code snippets to the default webconfig.

```
<protocolMapping>
  <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
  <!--add the following line to support http protocol-->
  <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="http"/>
</protocolMapping>
```

Then publish the project to the IIS folder and add the http binding to the IIS site binding module. We might need to enable the WCF support.
[image]
**Result.**
[image]
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.